# Would you reject an edit to a question asked 2 1/2 years ago?

Tags: discussion

This queue review link: https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/627069 The proposed edit is simply taking comments made 2 1/2 years ago and changing the question to reflect them.

Should I reject it because it's like mining for points without accomplishing anything for the OP or anyone searching on the problem? I could spend all day and night going through old posts and entering the comments into the OP question.

If I'm commenting with the OP in `real time` and something new comes up I'll update the question with tags or change the title perhaps, but generally only ask them to update the question with new information such as output from a command.

Answer (score 10):

I would have accepted that edit. It is adding an important  piece of information: that the OP was connecting from an OSX machine. OSX interactive shells are login shells by default, which means they behave differently. The relevant difference here is that they read the `*profile*` family of files (`~/.bash_profile` if present, `~/.profile` if not) instead of `~/.bashrc` on startup. That's an important point.

In general, I approve of any edit that adds useful information to the question. Old or new makes absolutely no difference whatsoever. Remember that the Stack Exchange sites are trying to build a *repository* of information. Someone might come and read that question a few years from now, so if it's in good shape, so much the better.

So, as long as an edit is improving the post, it should be accepted. That's a good thing. We want our posts to be clear, grammatically correct, and informative. Any edit that makes them more so is welcome.

Answer (score -5):

Reject the edit because the information added in the edit is irrelevant and useless to the question, not because of its age.

Comment: I did reject it. Can you read my rejection reasons in the queue? Oh I saw someone say `Mint` in comments because Nvidia has great support there. Does your wolfbot tell you? :D

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Then you did the right thing! And no, WolfBot only listens to questions.

Comment: Ahhh... Then the secret Mint society could be operating under your radar posting comments to brainwash Ubuntu users to the other side!!!

Comment: The edit is neither irrelevant nor useless to the question. The fact that the OP was using OSX is very relevant since that explains why the change had to be made in `~/.bash_profile` and not `~/.bashrc`.